# Daily Routine Workflow in Orchard 1.7

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I need to create a workflow that runs a daily routine. 
Is this possible? 
If, so. How will it fire?

The workflow will only have to delete some content from the DB when their 'expiry date' has passed.

Could do in code, but think everyone will benefit from it.

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my module: https://ambaworkflow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest
It contains Periodical Event. 
It is alfa, but it works...

[image]

For deleting expired content you can create your own activity, like this: https://ambaworkflow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Activities/WriteEventLogActivity.cs